# Creating spring threadpool with spring managed thread

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I'm trying to learn spring boot by migrating my java code to spring boot.

I have a part of Java code like this:

```
int threadLimit = 5, interval = 2;
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(threadLimit);
for (int i = 0; i < executionThreadLimit; i++) {
    WorkerThread worker = new WorkerThread("WorkerThread");
    ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(worker, 0, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Here `WorkerThread` implements `Runnable`;

Corresponding Spring boot alternative of above code:

Custom Pool class:

```
@Configuration
public class Test {

     @Bean
        public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
            ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
            threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
            threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
            return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
        }

}
```

WorkerThread class:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    private String threadName = null;

    @Autowired
    private AppParameter app;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        logger.info("Thread :: " + this + " is running -- > " + app.getA() + " && " + app.getB());
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@Component
public class TestCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    int threadLimit = 5, interval = 2000;  // these 2 are dynamic values but provided statically for testing purposes
    for(int i = 0; i< threadLimit; i++) {
        WorkerThread wt = new WorkerThread();
        taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(wt, interval);
    }
}
```

}

Now this is where my problem arises. If I need to start 5 `WorkerThread` instances, I have to do `WorkerThread wt = new WorkerThread();` But if do it this way, then `WorkerThread` wont be a spring managed bean anymore.

**So my question is how I can Create a threadpool with the thread class being a Spring Managed bean?**

I've only started working with spring boot, hence would someone mind helping me out a bit? Thanks.

I've already referred the following docs,
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler
https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-and-java-thread-example/
but couldn't come up with a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate them using `ObjectFactory`

```
@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

@Autowired
private ObjectFactory<WorkerThread> threadFactory;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    int threadLimit = 5, interval = 2000;  // these 2 are dynamic values but provided statically for testing purposes
    for(int i = 0; i< threadLimit; i++) {
        WorkerThread wt = threadFactory.getObject();
        taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(wt, interval);
    }
}
```